# C# - Create string with exactly entered chars

Tags: c#

I am creating http query string with "%2C"

```
query["destination"] = values[0] + @"%2C" + values[1];
```

but at the end, in final variable is result with %252C instead of %2C

```
48.18846%252C16.36502
```

How to fix this?

Comment: How are you determining what the string contains? If I create a test console app that does the above it prints out what I expect  - "48.18846%2C16.36502"

Comment: Is your `query` URL-encoded after that? Because if it is, you should just use `","`.

Comment: the `%` symbol gets converted to `%25`. Use just `,` in your string - it will be converted to `%2C`. See encoding [here](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)

Comment: %2C is for , (comma). Try `values[0] + "," + values[1];`. The input you provide are already url encoded. Check this for example - https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/?recipe=%5B%7B%22op%22%3A%22URL%20Decode%22%2C%22args%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%5D&input=YSUyY2I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**HttpUtility.UrlEncode**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) to encode your values don't do it manually.

```
string yourString = values[0] + "," + values[1];
string encodedString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourString);
```

Here [**full example in dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5EV4d)